# I am getting a link of an Image from backend and I have to set value in a file type input. and also have to post as a image on API in React JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am getting a link on an Image from backend and I have to set value in a file type input. and also have to post as a image on API.

**data**

`

```
  {
                "id": 41,
                "name": "2nd",
                "description": "2nd",
                "image": "https://unify.eoxyslive.com/images/freelancer-portfolio/demo%20img%202.jpg"
            },
```

`

**API Call**

```
 const submitPortfolio = (e) => {
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("title", values?.title);
    formData.append("description", values?.description);
    formData.append("image", portfolioImage);
    if (data) {
      formData.append("id", data?.id);
    }

    dispatch(onEditPortfolio(formData, onCloseModal));
  };
```

**File Type Input **

```
 <input
                    type="file"
                    id="drag_portfolio"
                    name="file"
                   onChange={(e) => onImageChange(e)}
                    value="https://unify.eoxyslive.com/images/freelancer-portfolio/demo%20img%202.jpg"
                  />
```

I am trying to send post request on API and getting the result
*{status: false, message: "The image must be an image."}
message
:
"The image must be an image."
status
:
false*

Please tell me what i need to do ?

***Thank You***

Comment: hello If anyone know the solution then please help...

Answer (score 0):

What backend are you using? (is it mongoDB)

Because with mongoDB you have to set the id key as **"_id"**

> MongoDB (Shown below)

```
{ "_id": 41,
   "name": "2nd",
   "description": "2nd",
   "image": "https://unify.eoxyslive.com/images/freelancerportfolio/demo%20img%202.jpg"
},
```

Hope this helps